# AS3 Button reference in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have two buttons that are in a movieclip, how can I reference them like I have done with the 2 buttons below so that they can be added into an array?

container.anotherButton and container.anotherButton2 are the buttons I want to add to the array.

```
var agreeButton:SimpleButton;
var disagreeButton:SimpleButton;

var buttonArray:Array = new Array(agreeButton, disagreeButton);

for (var i:int = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {    
   buttonArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the question is, I think this is what you need.

```
var buttonArray:Array = new Array(container.anotherButton, container.anotherButton2);
```

The reference will hold even if you move the container/buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I over complicated that.

Comment: The reference will hold, no matter how you re-add the components to display list, since every object's reference is unique and tied to the particular location of that object in machine's memory. The path to that object in Flash's display list has no effect to the reference's value.